# Change background, textcolor of AlertDialog

Tags: android, styles, android-dialog, android-theme

I try to change  **background** and **textcolor** of AlertDialog. 
But I can change only color of title with `android:windowTitleStyle` 
 
Activity: 
`AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,  R.style.AlertDialogCustom));`

styles.xml

`style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Holo.Theme.Sherlock"`

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
adb.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'><b>John:</b></font>"+"How are you?"))
```

this is for changing text color 
You can create you own dialog box 
check this link 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this

- [Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example)
- [Custom Dialog Box Popup using Layout in Android](http://www.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog"> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item> 
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item> 
</style> 
</resources>
```